# li:hover a visited colour

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, html-lists

I within my li element I have a link and some text contained within a span.

When I hover over the li I want to change the colour of the text and link, this works well, however I am struggling to set a visited colour and keep this functionality.

Here is my code -

HTML -

```
<ul id="progress" class="tour_1">
    <li>
       <span class="number"><a href="http://mylink.com">1</a></span>
       <span class="desc">A Link</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

CSS -

```
#progress li { float: left; width: 20%; text-align:center; font-size: 12px; color: #CCC; z-index: 10 }
#progress li .number { font-size: 24px; font-weight: 400; border: 2px solid #CCC; border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px; -moz-border-radius: 40px 40px 40px 40px; width: 30px; height: 30px; display: block; margin: 0 auto; background-color: #FFF }
#progress li:hover, li:hover a:hover { color: #333; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set a `visited` state like:

```
#progress li:hover a:visited
{
background-color:yellow;
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_visited.asp

Comment: Thanks, I had played around with lots of combinations and then realised I needed a visted state for hover and a visited for when not hovering! Been looking at code for too long! 
    `#progress li:hover, li:hover a:hover { color: #333; }
    #progress li:hover a:visited { color: #333 } 
    #progress a:visited {color: #CCC;}`