# How do I get the li tags to light up individually

Tags: jquery

How do I get the `li` tags to light up individually on mouseover all of the `li` tags light up at once

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").mouseover(function(){
   $("li").css("background-color","yellow");
 });
  $("li").mouseout(function(){
  $("li").css("background-color","lightgray");
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
 <ul class="menu">
 <li>Bookmarks</li>
 <li>Something</li>
 <li>BUMPER STICKERS</li>
 <li>CARBONLESS FORMS</li>
 <li>CD JACKETS</li>
 <li>DIE CUT/CUSTOM STICKERS</li>
 <li>DOOR HANGERS</li>
 <li>ENVELOPES</li>
 <li>FOLDERS</li>
 <li>LETTERHEADS</li>
 <li>RECTANGULAR STICKERS</li>
 <li>ROUND STICKERS</li>
 <li>STATIC CLING </li>
 <li>TABLE TENTS</li>
 <li>VINYL BANNERS</li>
<li>WINDOW STICKERS</li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Have a look at the link below :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968791/lihover-a-visited-colour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/whZYD/

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $("li").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css("background-color","yellow");
 });
  $("li").mouseout(function(){
  $(this).css("background-color","lightgray");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just use CSS?

```
li {
    background-color: lightgray;
}

li:hover {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 $("li").hover(function () {
     $(this).css("background-color", "yellow");
 }, function () {
     $(this).css("background-color", "lightgray");
 });
});
```

Or simply use Css:

```
li {
  background-color: lightgray;
}

li:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code:

```
    #page li:hover a:visited
    {
    background-color:green;
    }
```

Have a look at the link below :

[li:hover a visited colour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7968791/lihover-a-visited-colour)

http://htmlbook.ru/css/hover